# Shorten my if statements - Java

Tags: java, swing

I have looked for a while but the fact that my if statements also get their a selection from a radio button seems to have confused me a little.

```
if (male.isSelected()){
        p = "he"; p2 = "him";
    }
    if (female.isSelected()){
        p = "she"; p2 = "her";
    }
    if (nonBinary.isSelected()){
        p = "they"; p2 = "their";
    }
    if (sMale.isSelected()){
        p1 = "his"; p3 = "himself";
    }
    if (sFemale.isSelected()){
        p1 = "her"; p3 = "herself";
    }
    if (sNonBinary.isSelected()){
        p1 = "them"; p3 = "themself";
    }
```

I attempted an if, else if, else statement but my nonbinary button selection broke from that. This is working right now, but I want to see if there is a way to make it shorter.

Comment: you can start by using `else if`

Comment: @jhamon "I attempted an if, else if, else statement but my nonbinary button selection broke from that."

Comment: @Reimeus Thank you I will post there as soon as it will let me again.

Comment: @Reimeus Not with the current lack of context, no. This question has no place on Code Review in this state.

Comment: @GhostCat None of the given answers really met my needs.  I ended up making another class with a switch statement and a constructor in the main GUI. It looks better now and works the way it is still supposed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the given answers worked with the program as needed or didn't shorten the code as I was hoping. But, I was able to find a solution that shortened it a little as well as got it out of my main and wanted to share it here for others to see.

```
static String p,p1,p2,p3;
    gender(String selfGender){

    if (null != selfGender) 
    switch (selfGender) {
        case "Male":
            p="he";
            p1="his";
            p2="him";
            p3="himself";
            break;
        case "Female":
            p="she";
            p1="her";
            p2="her";
            p3="herself";
            break;
        case "Non Binary":
            p="they";
            p1="them";
            p2="their";
            p3="themself";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This was the code I put into another class to hold my gender info, I did this again for gender2 for the other user input as well.

```
gender gender1 = new gender(selfGender);
```

This was put into my main class to call the information and use in the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [ButtonGroup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton) with your radiobuttons.

```
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(male);
group.add(female);
group.add(nonbinary);
```

With a ButtonGroup you need not store the individual JRadioButton-s as fields.

So you might get the state (selected object) from the group. Use a data model:

```
static class Gender {
    final String p;
    final String p2;
    Gender(String p, String p2) {
        this.p = p;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }
}
```

Though this actually might not be shorter, there is less fluff, and the code is more to the point, and less error prone.

Comment: This is the answer i should have gone for as well. eliminates the need for conditionals completely in this case.

Comment: If I understand this right by doing it like this I could remove my male and Small options and instead just find the one to use from the button group correct? I had button groups around the S button and then the regular buttons. I didn't think each gender.

Comment: There is a problem with this option because it will not allow more than one male button to be selected. I need more than one to be available.

Comment: One could have more than one button group, every group  representing a one-of selection.

Answer (score 1):

Abstractions would be helpful. In the simplest form, like:

```
final static Pair<String, String> MALE = new Pair<>("he", "him");
...
```

That would allow you to go:

```
if (male.isSelected()) {
  p1 = MALE.getFirst(); p2 = MALE.getSecond();
```

Next step: drop the code duplication:

```
Pair<String, String> selectedPair = null);
if (male.isSelected) selectedPair = MALE;
else if (female.isSelected) selectedPair = FEMALE;
...

p1 = selectedPair.getFirst(); p2 = ...
```

Then, you could step further back and think if there could be some sort of mapping, that allows you to go

```
Map<Whatever, Pair<String, String>> mappedPairs = ...
```

to be used somehow like:

```
Pair<String, String> selectedPair = mappedPairs.get(X);
p1 = selectedPair.getFirst(); p2 = ...
```

That `X` thing is of course the tricky part here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an Enum to hold all the possible genders You have, Like

```
private enum genderStates {
         male,
         female,
         nonBinary,
         sMale,
         sFemale,
         sNonBinary;
}
```

Then to keep track of which gender is currently selected use a field such as

```
private genderStates currentGender = genderStates.male;
```

Comment: The "currentGender" field should hold the gender that is currently selected.